# Handle site certificate expiry with OkHttp Certificate pinning on Android

Tags: android, okhttp, pinning

I have an app that has a site certificate hash pinned with OkHttp3 similar to the method mentioned [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS#certificate-pinning)

The site certificate is about to expire soon though and I realized that I need to be able to support a new site certificate as soon as I switch update that on the site, as well as let the current one still work until then. Is there a way to pin 2 certificates for the same site so that both are supported seamlessly (i.e when the current one expires and one is no longer valid as well as the new one as soon it is updated)?

TIA

Comment: Call `add()` more that once, based on the `CertificatePinner` API.

Comment: cool! was hoping that would work but was not certain it would. Have you by any chance tried this and have it work for your apps?

Comment: "Have you by any chance tried this" -- no. Hence, my "based on the `CertificatePinner` API comment. :-) That being said, from my reading of the `CertificatePinner` JavaDocs, it sure sounds like it should handle this scenario. If it does not, file an enhancement request with OkHttp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the documented behaviour of CertificatePinner.  So just add pins for your current and old certificate.

http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html#check-java.lang.String-java.util.List-

> Confirms that at least one of the certificates pinned for hostname is
>   in peerCertificates. Does nothing if there are no certificates pinned
>   for hostname. OkHttp calls this after a successful TLS handshake, but
>   before the connection is used.

n.b. Because of the expiry of your certificates may happen before old clients update, it is usually advised to also pin against the CA you use also which is quite likely to be consistent across old and new certificates.  This will ensure even if your current and next certificate expire or are revoked, you would be able to authenticate with a new certificate generated and older clients.

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/hpkp-best-practices-if-you-choose-to-implement/4625